# Align two identical cards with constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to get the two cards to be identical squares aligned horizontally with 8dp margin on every sides.

Something like this :

[image: example]

I have tried using constraint layout and setting the ratio of the cards to 1:1, the cards are aligned and are squares but they are ridiculously small and do not match the entire layout.

here's my layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/background">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cards"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/card2"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Hey"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cards"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/card1"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Hey"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what I get :

[image: screenshot of the result]

I'm quite lost with constraint layout for now, so what should I do, and what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want the constraints to define the dimensions of a view, you have to set that dimension to `0dp`. So you should replace both `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` attributes on your two `CardView`s with `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

Next, you want to make sure that the cards expand to fill all the available space. So you should delete these two attributes from both cards:

```
card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
```

From there, just play around with the margins until the cards look like you want them to. Note that margins apply sort of strangely to chains (views can pass margins down the chain), so you probably only want to put left/right margin on the first card, while you should put top/bottom margin on both (since it's a horizontal chain, the horizontal margins are "shared").

Comment: Thanks, putting left/right margin on the first card works well.

Answer (score 1):

hi @Mpk605 try setting the width of both the cardviews to 0dp.Now since they are wrap_content the cardview wraps around the text and so it looks small . It will enlarge as the text becomes large (you can try that).
Setting width to 0dp is equal to setting it as match_parent. Thus it will fill all the space available after the matching the specified constraint.